# How to register an application to a uri scheme in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, url, uri, url-scheme

Mac OS Applications can register for custom uri schemes through their Info.plist file by specifying [CFBundleURLTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1). In order to add another uri scheme the Application bundle needs to be modified.

The question is: how do I add an additional uri scheme for an already installed application, without changing the Application itself. Bonus points if this can be done from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use [RCDefaultApp preference pane](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/), which is free. I think it manages these CFBundleURLTypes (and more) for you.

It's point and click. I'd like to hear about a command-line option, too.

Answer (score 1):

[defaultapp](https://github.com/Grayson/defaultapp) is a simple command line tool that does this. You need to download and built it yourself though.

You can then use a command like `defaultapp ftp Transmit` to set Transmit as the default app for ftp.

Comment: Any idea how to use a shell script as the "default application"?

Comment: You could create an Applescript script that runs the shell script. Then save that script as an Application. Then follow the steps here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinCastor (http://onflapp.wordpress.com/lincastor/) for that. Can associate an URL protocol scheme with an AppleScript, shell script or existing application.